# Making a simple calculator in Python and not sure how to do nothing for else

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that simply adds or subtracts 2 numbers. I have the code below:

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
y = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print("Would you like to add or subtract?")
txt = input("Type 'a' for add or 's' for subtract")
if txt == "a" or "A":
    x + y == z 
    if txt == "s" or "S":
        x - y == z 
    else: 
        return
else:
    return
print (z)
```

I know the return isn't right but not sure how I should work this out.

Comment: `x - y == z ` is  it typo or intended? if your code inside function you can directly return `return x + y`

Comment: It's the mistake.

Comment: Didn't you mean to use `elif`? Right now you are checking that the input is `s` **after you already checked that it's `a`**...

Comment: By the way, you should be using: `txt.lower() == "a":` at first... `or "A"` doesn't do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: `x + y == z` is a test for equality. It checks if `x + y` and `z` are equal. To *assign the result* of `x + y` to `z`, you need to do `z = x + y`.

For such problems, it really helps to draw a flowchart or at least write out the steps you are going to implement in your code, especially when you're beginning programming. Here's an example. Pay attention to the indentation of my numbered list. This is similar to the indentation that you will expect to see in your Python code.

1. Take two numbers

   - `input()`  returns a string, so convert to integers
2. Ask for the operator

   - `input()` to take a string.
3. If the operator is "a" or "A" (See note 1)

   - do addition
4. *Instead*, if the operator is "s" or "S"

   - do subtraction
5. If the operator is none of the above

   - *do nothing? Show an error?*
6. In the end, print the output

The code for the algorithm we discussed above would be:

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: ")) # 1.
y = int(input("Enter a number: ")) # 1.
print("Would you like to add or subtract?") # 2.
txt = input("Type 'a' for add or 's' for subtract")
if txt == "a" or txt == "A": # 3.
    z = x + y
elif txt == "s" or txt == "S": # 4.
    z = x - y
else: # 5.
    z = 0
    print("Invalid choice!")

print (z) # 6.
```

Your code goes wrong here:

3. If the operator is "a" or "A"

   - do addition

   1. Now, if the operator is "s" or "S" **(Can it be "s" or "S"? *No*, because we already established that it's "a" or "A" in `3.` above )**

      - do subtraction

---

**Note 1**: In human languages, we say

> Check if `txt` is "a" or "A"

But Python works with booleans for the `if` condition. If we did `if txt == "a" or "A"`, this would evaluate to `if [[(txt == "a") is true] or ["A" is true]]`. Because non-empty strings are truthy in Python, `["A" is true]` would always be correct and so `[[(txt == "a") is true] or ["A" is true]]` would always be `true`, so we'd always go into the `if` statement. Not what we wanted to happen!
We have to compare each one separately like so:

```
if txt == "a" or txt == "A":
```

Alternatively, we can convert `txt` to lower or upper case and have a single check

```
if txt.lower() == "a":
```

Or,

```
if txt.upper() == "A":
```

Alternatively, we could check whether `txt` is one of the elements in a list.

```
if txt in ["a", "A"]:
```

Comment: I really like the recommendation to use a flowchart or write out my code. I took intro to Programming like 2 years ago and forgot all about planning out my code before diving in. I'll surly be doing this in the future,.

Answer (score 2):

first of all when you write:

```
x + y == z
```

you are not defining a new z variable, but just making the logical operation "is x + y equal to z?" where z is not even defined. If you want to define z as the sum or difference of x and y you should use:

`z = x + y` or `z = x - y`

Also, when you want to make a structure of the kind "if condition is equal to something, else if condition is equal to something else" you can use if, else and elif (which is both else and if togheter), but you have to be sure that they have the same indentation.

The following code should do the job: (Edited)

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
y = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print("Would you like to add or subtract?")
txt = input("Type 'a' for add or 's' for subtract")
if txt == "a" or txt=="A":
    z = x + y 
elif txt == "s" or txt=="S":
    z = x - y 
print (z)
```

Edit: you did not define a function, therefore you don't need to use "return". Return is used to give the result of a function, for example:

```
def sum(x, y):
    z = x + y 
    return(z)
```

Edit #2: Thank you for making me note that `txt == 'a' or 'A'` would always be true, i've now repaired the code.

Comment: Thank you for making me note that! I've edtited the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have seen the error of my ways! Haha.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do `z = x + y` and `z = x - y` instead of `x + y == z` and `x - y == z`. Double equals to is a comparison operator.

The below code should work:

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
y = int(input("Enter a number: "))
z = 0
print("Would you like to add or subtract?")
txt = input("Type 'a' for add or 's' for subtract")
if txt == "a" or "A":
    z = x + y
elif txt == "s" or "S":
    z = x - y
//you can use return if it's a function
return z;   
print (z)
```

Comment: He wants to return a value, so I believe his code is part of a function.

Comment: Python comments are started with a `#`

Comment: `if txt == "a" or "A":` is always `True`